# How to get the date period of the grouped list?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to get the data list group by 3 or 4 days so I use GroupBy to group it.

```
list.GroupBy(o => new { OrderDate = (o.OrderDate.DayOfYear - 1) / o.User.CheckoutPeriod,o.UserId});
```

The `OrderDate` is the date of the data. the `o.CheckoutPeriod` is the days maybe 3 or 4;

and I will get a `List`, how to get the start date and the end date of each item in the `List`?

```
Id  OrderDate      OrderMoney OrderCount UserId
1    2020-04-15        10          2        1
2    2020-04-16        15          3        2
3    2020-04-17        16          1        1
4    2020-04-18        17          3        2
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense to me: `o.OrderDate.DayOfYear` will be which day in the year the order falls on, expressed as an integer in the range 1-366, and `o.CheckoutPeriod` will be 3 or 4.  Why are you then dividing them?  Is the idea that you want to group your orders into orders with overlapping check out periods?

Comment: I want to dividing the orders by the order create date 3 or 4 days for every group. I mean three or four days orders is in the same group. it is same with every week.@simon-pearson

Comment: Do all orders have the same `CheckoutPeriod`?  It'd help if you added some sample data to your code sample.

Comment: @simon-pearson thank you. I added the data. and changed the group linq. the CheckoutPerios is in the User and for the user it is a const int value. and I want to group by the user and this users'checkout Perios.